# How to utlilize Error Collector for junit testing methods with parameters

Tags: java, junit4, errorcollector

I am using ErrorCollector in my Junit test case with the aim of printing out the errors and not stopping at the erroneous locations.
I successfully tried the ErrorCollector by using methods without parameters. However to reduce code duplicacy (i wrote the same method 6 times
without the parameter ; since i am using 6 files for comparison as seen in my code), 
I would like to have a generic method that can be used to achieve the same purpose of printing out errors and continuing with the check.
When i tried using the method with a parameter i got the exception "Method should have no parameters"..

The following is my code.

```
            import org.gdal172.ogr.ogr;
            import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
            import org.junit.Rule;
            import org.junit.Test;
            import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;
            import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
            import org.junit.runner.Result;
            import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

            public class DGNTester {
                private ReadDGN readDgn = new ReadDGN();
                private LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> layerMapCountForCompare = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
                @Rule
                public  ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

                private File output = null;
                static {
                    // perform OGR format registration once
                    if (ogr.GetDriverCount() == 0)
                        ogr.RegisterAll();
                }

                /**
                 * @param args
                 */
                public static void main(String[] args) {

                    DGNTester dTest = new DGNTester();

                    String dgnFileName_43k10 = "input\\43k10.dgn";
                    String dgnFileName_43k11 = "input\\43k11.dgn";
                    String dgnFileName_43k12 = "input\\43k12.dgn";

                    //The six files iam using as input.

                    dTest.test(dgnFileName_43k10, "dvd");
                    dTest.test(dgnFileName_43k10, "all");
                    dTest.test(dgnFileName_43k11, "dvd");
                    dTest.test(dgnFileName_43k11, "all");
                    dTest.test(dgnFileName_43k12, "dvd");
                    dTest.test(dgnFileName_43k12, "all");

                }

                @Test
                public void test(String fileName, String inputType) {
                    System.out.println("FOR FILE -->" + fileName);
                    System.out
                            .println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    String fileIdentifier = fileName.substring(6, 11);
                    String dstFilePath = null;
                    String outputName = null;
                    if (layerMapCountForCompare != null)
                        layerMapCountForCompare.clear();

                    if (inputType.equals("dvd")) {
                        dstFilePath = "F:\\eclipse_helios_3.6.1_64_bit_with_jre_and_add-ons\\eclipse\\Resources\\DST\\dvd.dst";
                        outputName = "output\\outputfile_" + fileIdentifier
                                + "_dvd.dst.txt";
                    }
                    if (inputType.equals("all")) {
                        dstFilePath = "F:\\eclipse_helios_3.6.1_64_bit_with_jre_and_add-ons\\eclipse\\Resources\\DST\\AllLayers.dst";
                        outputName = "output\\outputfile_" + fileIdentifier + ".txt";
                    }
                    layerMapCountForCompare = readDgn.getLayerFeatureCount(fileName,
                            dstFilePath);

                    // Read the text output file and Compare with the map. These are the six out put files against each input file

                    output = new File(outputName);

                    if (output.exists()) {
                        try {
                            Set keys = layerMapCountForCompare.keySet();
                            Iterator itr = keys.iterator();
                            String key = "";
                            Integer val;

                            String line;
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(output));
                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && itr.hasNext()) {
                                key = (String) itr.next();
                                val = layerMapCountForCompare.get(key);
                                String compare = key + "=" + val;
                                compare.trim();
                                line.trim();
                                //When i print this out in a positive scenario; i am able to see the values of 'compare' and 'line' as same
                                /*System.out.println("COMPARE >>> " + compare
                                        + " --------------- AND --------- Line " + line);*/

                                assertEquals("Comparing input and output", line, compare);
                            }
                            br.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Output file does not exist");
                    }

                }

                public void assertEquals(String msg, Object expected, Object actual) {

                    collector.checkThat(actual, CoreMatchers.equalTo(expected));

                }

            }
```

In my previous example; where i did not use parameters;

```
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(DGNTester.class);

    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
                System.out.println(failure.toString());
            }
            if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Tests finished successfully...");
            }
```

This code helped in triggering the test methods and print the appropriate methods.
Can you please guide me as to how I can use my generic method thet takes two parameters to utilize the ErrorCollector.

How to utlilize Error Collector for junit testing methods with parameters

Answer (score 0):

The `@Test` annotation **doesn't support test methods with parameters in the signature**.

**Example:**

Trying to run the method `brokenTest` an exception will be thrown. A correct test method in JUnit should look like `correctTest`:

```
/** This method uses parameters in the signature. It will not work! */
@Test
public void brokenTest(String fileName) {...}

/** This correct test method has no parameters in its signature. */
@Test
public void correctTest() {...}
```

**Parameterized tests with JUnit**

To support **parameterized testing** you can use the **@RunWith(Parameterized.class)** annotation (class-level).

The test class needs a static method that returns the parameters in an `Iterable` (like a `List` object). Annotate this method with `@Parameters`.

Furthermore you need a `public`(!) member variable for each parameter used, each one annotated with `@Parameter(0)`, `@Parameter(1)`, and so on.

Thus JUnit will run `testWithParameters()` for each test case produced with the `createParameters()` method. It will automatically assign the correct parameters to the @Parameter(N) fields (firstParameter/secondParameter).

You can produce as many parameters as you need.

Use these parameters in your test methods as needed by refering to their field names.

**Example with an excerpt of the class you provided:**

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class DGNTester {
    @Rule
    public  ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    /**
     * Method that generates the parameters.
     * Each testValues.add(...) line produces a new test case.
     *
     * @return Array with test values.
     */
    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> createParameters() {
        List<Object[]> testValues = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            testValues.add(new Object[]{"pre-Case1-Value1", "Case1-Value2"});
            testValues.add(new Object[]{"Case2-Param1", "Case2-Value2"});
            testValues.add(new Object[]{"pre-Case3-Value1", "Case3-Value2"});
        }

        return testValues;
    }

    /** The first parameter. */
    @Parameter(0)
    public String firstParameter;

    /** The second parameter. */
    @Parameter(1)
    public String secondParameter;

    /** Test using the parameters generated by createParameters(). 
      * In this example we check, if the first parameter is equal to the
      * concatenation of the String "pre-" and the second parameter */
    @Test
    public void testWithParameters() {
        assertThat("Wrong parameter values", firstParameter, 
            is("pre-" + secondParameter));
    }

    ...
}
```